# Plotly figure_factory create_ternary_contour is ignoring my negative values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, contour, plotly-python

I am trying to create a ternary contour plot.  I have a dataframe; I will reproduce a small portion of it here to show what the data looks like and verify that some of the values are significantly negative:

```
5118  9.400000e-01  1.000000e-02  5.000000e-02 -1.060181e+01 -1.120589e+17
5119  9.400000e-01  2.000000e-02  4.000000e-02 -3.296350e+00  1.289571e+16
5120  9.400000e-01  3.000000e-02  3.000000e-02 -1.457624e+00 -2.091266e+16
5121  9.400000e-01  4.000000e-02  2.000000e-02 -7.063785e+00  9.875624e+16
5122  9.400000e-01  5.000000e-02  1.000000e-02  3.561383e+01  1.651944e+22
5123  9.400000e-01  6.000000e-02  5.551115e-17  2.616823e+06  2.196856e+25
5124  9.500000e-01  1.000000e-10  5.000000e-02 -1.765131e+03  1.905280e+21
5125  9.500000e-01  1.000000e-02  4.000000e-02 -8.078167e+00 -1.006010e+18
5126  9.500000e-01  2.000000e-02  3.000000e-02 -1.770320e+00 -1.634174e+16
5127  9.500000e-01  3.000000e-02  2.000000e-02 -6.281301e+00  1.605171e+17
5128  9.500000e-01  4.000000e-02  1.000000e-02  3.784604e+01  1.770413e+22
5129  9.500000e-01  5.000000e-02  4.163336e-17  2.615529e+06  2.207487e+25
5130  9.600000e-01  1.000000e-10  4.000000e-02 -1.313158e+03  4.112307e+21
5131  9.600000e-01  1.000000e-02  3.000000e-02 -3.084623e+00 -2.105711e+18
5132  9.600000e-01  2.000000e-02  2.000000e-02 -4.712708e+00  2.443321e+17
5133  9.600000e-01  3.000000e-02  1.000000e-02  4.132105e+01  9.425646e+21
5134  9.600000e-01  4.000000e-02  3.469447e-17  2.584927e+06  2.169316e+25
5135  9.700000e-01  1.000000e-10  3.000000e-02 -3.132881e+02  5.630057e+21
5136  9.700000e-01  1.000000e-02  2.000000e-02  2.507589e+00 -1.761395e+18
5137  9.700000e-01  2.000000e-02  1.000000e-02  4.214579e+01 -2.320810e+22
5138  9.700000e-01  3.000000e-02  2.775558e-17  2.002638e+06  1.308322e+25
```

(The headers are: x1, x2, x3, sigma, and delta.)

The command I am attempting is

```
fig = ff.create_ternary_contour(np.array([df['x1'],df['x2'],df['x3']]),
                                df['sigma'],pole_labels=['water','acetone','hexane'],
                                interp_mode='cartesian',
                                showscale=True)
```

However, the figure I get looks like this:
[nearly featureless ternary plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqoCP.png)
I can clearly see negative values in the thousands, and I have a zero-value contour computed from other code (which I am trying to cross-check with this image) that indicates that there should be significant "contour action" in this plot.  I found another report that plotly.express ignores negative values, but no one responded to that question, so it was of no help.

I have never managed to get `create_ternary_contour` to work for me, so I am probably doing something stupid.  I don't even care if I use this package: I just want a method of visualizing the contours of my data – any package will do (although if the contour coordinates are extractable, all the better).  Any help would be appreciated!